# Flexbox issues on the ipad/iphone

Tags: css, ios, iphone, ipad, flexbox

I need some help from IOS users :) I have recently made some changes to a site I built a few years back. One of the things it has is a garment configurator where you can choose garments, colours and designs. The configurator used to use javascript to work out the heights of the garments, but things have changed and I decided to just use CSS:

```
.kit-template {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 20px auto;

    .svg-document {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    svg {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &.large {
        height: 500px;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this uses flex and it seems very simple. When I built the site originally, flex was no as supported as it is now.
Anyway, since the changes I have been getting reports of the garments not looking right on iphones/ipads.

[image]

I spent hours trying to configure a virtual machine where I could use safaris development tools.
I finally managed it and when I looked, it worked fine lol. So it appears to only be an issue on an iPhone/iPad.

Here is a link to an actual example:

https://www.kudos-sports.com/designer/ideas?kitId=4119

If you look at that on an iPhone/iPad it just looks wrong and isn't applying my CSS.
Has anyone experienced this before or does anyone know what the issue might be?
I have spent far too long on trying to get this to work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your SVG is that you have applied 100% width to it and its container.

If you do

```
.kit-template .svg-document, .kit-template svg { width: auto }
```

that should fix your issue.

Comment: This didn't work. It actually seems to have made it worse, because now they bleed into each other: https://www.kudos-sports.com/designer/ideas?kitId=4130

Comment: I think I may have fixed it by adding `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center` to .svg-document